# PowerShell runas different to starting PowerShell as Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell

Running the command below in an elevated PowerShell console works and creates the virtual drive.

```
New-VHD -Path c:\vm_vol\Base.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB
```

However, running the command below in a non-elevated shell:

```
runas /user:$env:userdomain\$env:username "New-VHD -Path c:\vm_vol\Base.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB"
```

prompts for password, and attempts to run command:

```
Enter the password for dom1\user1:  
Attempting to start New-VHD -Path c:\vm_vol\Base.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB as user "dom1\user1" ...
```

but then gives the error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - New-VHD -Path c:\vm_vol\Base.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I get this command to work from a non-elevated shell?

Comment: `runas` have no knowledge of PowerShell's cmdlets and can not run them. Although it can run `powershell.exe` which know about PowerShell's cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl  Simply adding `powershell  ` to the beginning of the command in quotes fixed the problem.  (Although, I don't necessarily like momentarily opening up a 2nd shell to do this.)  Please put these in an answer and I will select it as the correct answer.    Is there a PowerShell `runas` command equivalent that would have knowledge of PowerShell's cmdlets?   Thanks

Comment: @Clay sometimes, cmdlets have a `-credential` parameter, where you can pass credential objects directly to your command, e.g `New-VHD -Path c:\vm_vol\Base.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB -Credential (Get-Credential)`, if they haven't you can `Invoke-Command { your-command } -Credential (Get-Credential)` - you can even automatically create the credential object, so you wouldn't have to type your username / pw all the time

Comment: Thanks @SimonS However, using `-credential $cred` gives the error: `New-VHD : The 'CimCredential' parameter requires that the 'ComputerName' parameter` and then using `-ComputerName $env:computername -credential $cred` gives the error: `New-VHD : User credentials cannot be used for local connections.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [PetSerAl](https://superuser.com/users/364455/petseral) suggested, using `runas /user:$env:userdomain\$env:username  "powershell -NoExit", "Get-VM"` will work.

However, I did the following to keep things less verbose in the long run.

#### Function to execute command in an elevated PowerShell session.

`psudo.ps1`:

```sh
function psudo ([string]$cmd = "echo Hello!") {
    Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-NoExit", $cmd
}

if ($args[0] -eq $null) {
    $cmd = "echo 'please provide powershell command to execute in elevated shell as a quoted string'"
} else {
    $cmd = $args[0]    
}

psudo $cmd
```

Running `psudo` from non-elevated shell:

```sh
psudo "echo 'This is a test using psudo'"
```

Result in elevated console that stays open:

```
This is a test using psudo
```

Running `psudo` to execute PowerShell cmdlet `Get-VM`, which needs elevation:

```sh
psudo Get-VM
```

Result in elevated console that stays open:

```
Name    State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status             Version
----    ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------             -------
test_vm Off   0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally 9.0
```

---

I just really wish I could get this to work with an `Invoke-Command` so I could see the results in the same console and not have to open up a separate window every time I want to run a command as an admin.

However, I could not get any version of something similar to the following to work:

#### Get and store credentials

Script file `getcreds.ps1` saved in a directory in my user folder that is also in my `$env:PATH` variable.  This way I only enter my password once, and only once every time it has to change for security policy.

`getcreds.ps1`:

```sh
function getcurcreds {
    $pwd = Get-Content "$HOME\ExportedPassword.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:username", $pwd

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement -ErrorAction Stop
    $Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
    $ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
    $pc = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext $ct, $Domain
    $validated = $pc.ValidateCredentials($cred.UserName, $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password)

    if (-Not $validated) {
        $cred = Get-Credential -UserName "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:username" -Message "WK NA password"
        Set-Content "$HOME\ExportedPassword.txt" ($cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString)
    }
    $cred
}

getcurcreds
```

#### Function modification to execute command in elevated PowerShell session and return results to current non-elevated PowerShell session.

`psudo.ps1`:

```sh
$cred = getcreds

function psudo ([string]$cmd = "echo Hello!") {
    $cmdBlk = [scriptblock]::Create(
        "Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoExit', $cmd"
    )
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:computername $cmdBlk -RunAsAdministrator -Credential $cred
}
```

I keep getting errors like:

`Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

or

```
cmdlet Invoke-Command at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ContainerId[0]:
```